# How to printing text on image in PHP for characters beyond ascii 127?

Tags: php, gd

I am using the PHP GD library API - imagettftext, to print texts on images. I am trying to print the left and right double quotes (i.e. ones with HTML entities “ and ”) on it. As per the documentation I print the text `'&#147;'` for `“`.

On my local system it works, but not on my production server. On server I am running:-

```
PHP 5.3.7 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2011 19:02:25)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Do you use the same version of gd and of the libraries gd uses? `php_info()` to the rescue.

Comment: What's the problem? Error messages? Crashes? Nothing printed? Wrong character printed? Garbled output?

Comment: @Juhana It prints empty boxes.

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't have a font that supports that range of characters.

Comment: @Juhana I have copied the font to the server and I explicitly pass the path of the font to the API.

Comment: Are your multibyte settings correct? Do your strings match the encoding you have set?

Comment: @Shi GD versions are same but libPNG versions are not same.

Comment: @tdammers How do check for multibyte settings? Where do we set the encoding you are speaking about?

Comment: @AppleGrew: `mb_internal_encoding` and its companions. http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php

Comment: @tdammers For both local and production servers it returns `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Seeme like an obvious character set issue. Checkout http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php for more info, but i would assume your issue would be resolved by changing your iconv.internal_encoding to something that supports your characters.

```
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

I'd give that a shot ;)